# Python начало..ошибка Typeerror 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
def bank(a,year):    
    for i in year:
     a=a + a*0.1        
    return print(a)
```

простенькая программа..при компиляции выдаёт ошибку

> Python37\bank.py", line 3, in bank
>       for i in year: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

не пойму в чем дело

Comment: В том, что year имеет тип int, =>, строка for i in year не имеет место быть. Если нужен цикл от 0 до year (включительно), используйте метод range(year+1).

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: int не является итерируемым объектом, а цикл, как вы поняли, проходится только по любому итерируемому объекту (строка, список и др.).

Comment: ага, понял спасибо

Comment: `return print(a)` не имеет смысла, т.к. print все равно вернет None. Можно просто сделать `print(a)`